# Advanced sequence alignment

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, dynamic-programming, sequences

Assume the following generative model for plagiarism:

The plagiarist:
1. Removes parts of the text
2. Rearranges parts of the text
3. Adds new text.

Ex. If ABCD is the original text (A,B,C and D can be paragraphs or bunch of sentences), the output can be DEAFCG where E,F and G are additional text added.

Also, the plagiarist is going to add small errors (insertion, substitution and deletion at small rates).

How do we go about detecting this instance of plagiarism?

What I have done so far: Tried using longest common subsequence method. It detects one linear set of matched text. In the above example, it would either detect D or AC (depending on their length)

What I need: A principled way of dealing with this problem. Any citations to pre-existing literature would be very helpful. Any pseudo code for ideas is also good. No code please.

This is neither homework, nor an interview question. I have simplified my practical problem into this toyish problem.

Comment: Based on some of your astute answers, I figured that if you're asking a question, it must be a challenging one! here's one article you probably saw - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism_detection

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of algorithms for doing this for numerous applications. As far as I can tell, what they mostly  do (and what you want to do) is to calculate the Edit Distance:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

There are a number of different algorithms that differ slightly, according to
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Relationship_with_other_edit_distance_metrics:

e.g. longest common subsequence handles addition and deletion but not substitution;
Damerau-Levenshtein distance also takes into account substitution, as well as transposition of adjacent characters.

Comment: I have already implemented longest common subsequence which uses edit distance. But it does not handle relocations (eg. ABC to CAB)

Comment: As far as I understand, there are different algorithms for edit distance which handle different cases (e.g. substitution, transposition)

Comment: But this is transposition at a large scale. A, B, C are large paragraphs or bunch of sentences, not one letter.

Comment: The only idea I can suggest in that case is some form of hierarchical approach. For example: (1) tokenize your input strings by hashing entire paragraphs to unique values, so now you have an alphabet that consists of these tokens (where each token actually represents a whole paragraph); (2) perform longest common subsequence/edit distance/whatever on the sequence of **tokens**

Comment: @maditya The only problem is that inside these paragraphs changes can also be made, so the hashes would not match up. And it could probably be entire paragraphs or sentences or parts of sentences that gets rearranged, which complicates it a lot more.